# mkdir with date function behaves differently in script

Tags: bash, date, cygwin, mkdir

I am trying to create a directory with a timestamp. If I type at the prompt

```
mkdir "$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S)"
```

I get a directory named with the date as I would like. If I put the same line in a bash script I get some strange characters at the end of the name. What is going on? I am attempting this in Cygwin and tried `bash` and `sh`.

Comment: Can you post an actual script and the actual output you get?

Comment: It's probably your `$PATH` and/or shell builtins/functions/aliases. Verify that `command -V date` and `ENV=/dev/fd/0 sh <<< 'command -V date'` produce the same output.

Comment: Or... And I should have noticed this before... You should definitely be quoting the `+...` bit like `"$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S')"` - though I'm not certain off the top of my head why that would behave differently in a script than at the prompt.

Comment: Check your `LC_TIME`

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with Cygwin. You need to run

```
dos2unix mkdatedir.sh  # or whatever your script is called
```

this will remove any dos carriage returns

but better to set option  igncr

see https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2010-08/msg00015.html

Comment: Ahh, very good. This makes perfect sense.